# How to wait async data to start sync function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get some data from an api call and set them in a state. Then I use this state variable in another function to filter some data. When the user opens the interface for the first time the data doesnt show because the sync function gets the empty data from the state.

Here is the code :

```
const [evQuestion, setEvQuestion] = useState();
const [answers, setAnswers] = useState();

const getEvaluationsQuestionsByOrganizations = async (evalId) => {
    const response = await apiStandarts.get(`/evaluation-questions?organization_evaluation=${evalId}`);
    setEvQuestion(response.data);
  };

  const evAnswers = () => {

    const evAnswers = questions.map(q => {
        return evQuestion?.map(ev => {
          return q.question_options.find(i => i.id === ev.questOptionId)
        });
      });
      const filterAnswers = evAnswers.map(q => {
        return q?.filter(Boolean)
      })
      const answersToObject = filterAnswers.map(item => {
        return convertArrayToObject(item)
      });
      const arr = {...answersToObject}
    const obj2 = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(arr).map(([key, value]) => [key, value])
    )
     const obj3=  Object.values(obj2).map(item => {
        return {[item.question]: {...item}}
      })
      const savedAnswers = convertArrayToObject(obj3);
      console.log(savedAnswers)
      setAnswers(savedAnswers)
    }

useEffect(() => {
 getEvaluationsQuestionsByOrganizations();
 evAnswers();
}, [])
```

I've tried to wrap the `evAnswers` function in a settimeout function but with no luck. How can I achieve this, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another `useEffect` hook that depends on `evQuestion` state.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 getEvaluationsQuestionsByOrganizations();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 evAnswers();
}, [evQuestion]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this totally flew over my head, such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

the function `getEvaluationsQuestionsByOrganizations(..)` is defined as **async** function, but you are using it **synchronously**, in that case you should call your codes as below:

```
useEffect(() => {
 const fetchedDataAPI = async () => {
    return await getEvaluationsQuestionsByOrganizations();
 };

 fetchedDataAPI
  .then(res => { evAnswers();})
  .catch(err => {..});
;

}, []);
```